# How to keep all the applications I've opened showing on my external monitor when I close laptop

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a Macbook Pro running Mojave 10.14.4 with an external montior, I have set up mirrored display and made the external monitor my primary display.

When I close the lid the monitor goes black, as expected, when I press key to get it to light up again all the applications I opened while the lid was opened are not shown on the external monitor. If I open up the lid the monitors go black and I press a key I can see all applications on both monitors. As I hope to just come in, plug in my Macbook  and see what I'm working on in my primary monitor it would be nice if I did not have to open up my secondary monitor to do so.

Comment: In mirroring mode, there is no primary or secondary display. Both the displays are identical.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the displays set to mirrored, they should be identical.

When you disconnect the external monitor, the windows must go somewhere, which is to the built-in display. If it’s mirrored, there can’t be a primary display.

Comment: Ok but what is happening is not that it goes to my built in display when I disconnect the external monitor, or at any rate I don't care if that happens. My problem is that I have windows on my external monitor, I close my laptop, windows no longer on my external monitor. I have tried with external window as primary monitor and I have tried with mirrored monitors, but when I close the laptop the external monitor does not get the opened windows, I can open new windows but I don't have the windows I was working on.